# What would be the mechanism of the given reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

**Problem:**

> [image]
>
> $\ce{A}$ can be?
>
> 1. concentrated sulphuric acid
> 2. alcoholic potassium hydroxide
> 3. triethylamine
> 4. potassium *tert*-butoxide

**My comments:**

**Option (A):** Conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$, is an acid, it gives $\ce{H+}$ ions which must act like electrophile and add to the double bond, which must produce a carbocation and then, $\ce{HSO4^-}$ ion must act like a nucleophile and form a bond with the carbocation. Hence, the reaction must be addition of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{HSO4^-}$

**Options (B),(C),(D):** are bases, with basicity order: (D) > (B) > (C). But what would they do to an alkene?

Answer given in the book is A. How is this so?

Comment: Under (A) you have heat added. What is to stop a second molecule reacting with the first under electrophilic addition to remove the H2SO4 as a good leaving group and give the product shown in the question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bottom line: $\ce{HSO4-}$ is a really bad nucleophile, and it doesn't enter in the picture.

[image]

(I realize after scanning that I'm missing the "+ H<sup>+</sup>" alongside the final product.)

---

Question for extra credit: after the second step, why is the third step (carbocation migration) favorable rather than directly reforming the double bond on the right-hand side ring?

Comment: Answer to extra credit: Because of the hydride migration, it forms a tertiary carbocation which is very much stable than secondary carbocation

Comment: In you second last step. You've removed a proton. I strongly advice my students not to just protons getting away. Instead, I ask them to show a base picking up a proton. Who took that proton? Last step is like an Elimination 1 reaction. Which usually needs a strong base, but I don't see a strong base here.

Comment: @claws the last step has nothing to do with an elimination. The carbocation is the [conjugate acid of the alkene](http://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/addene1.htm), so under acidic conditions it is formed in small amounts (equilibrium with alkene). The proton is not “picked up” by the base: this is an acidic solution, protons come and go all the time.